# How to set and get `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in a POJO in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I am using a POJO like this:

```
public class Pojo {
    String name;
    //Others
    Map<String, String> time; //As this is a Map<String,String>
    //Constructors, getters, setters etc.
}
```

Now I want this to upload to firebase

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Pojo pojo = new pojo;
        pojo.setName(getName());
        pojo.setTimeStamp(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP); //Is this right?
        String id = pojoFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
        shortcut.setId(id);
        shortcutDatabase.child(id).setValue(pojo);
    }
}
```

These all seems right to me. But when I see in my real-time database, I see that there is only one long (`"time" : 123456789`) in it. How is a `Map<String,String>` changed to a long?

Also when I try to get my pojo back (I am using [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database)) :

```
fbUIRecyclerAdapter =
    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Pojo, PojoViewHolder>(myOptions) {
    @Override
    public PojoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.pojo_view, parent, false);
        return new PojoViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(PojoViewHolder pView, int position, Pojo pojo) {
        pView.setName(pojo.getName());                      
        shortcutView.setTimestamp(shortcut.getTimeStamp());
    }
```

I get an exception:

`com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.Long`

It seems reasonable enough to me. Because there is only long in the database but I am asking for a `Map<String, String>` in my `Pojo.class`.

So how do I fix this? How to get the long in my Pojo object to use it with my needs?

Comment: Show your detail error log info .Show detail of `Pojo` .

Comment: My project is too huge to show in this question. I have actually no pojo, another object for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add map to your code `Map<String, String> time = new HashMap<>();`

2.put value to the map `time.put("time",ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);`

3.set in to Pojo `pojo.setTimeStamp(time);`

Try this .

```
    // add map
    Map<String, String> time = new HashMap<>();
    time.put("time",ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    // edited here ,change Pojo
    Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
    pojo.setName(getName());
    // edited here 
    pojo.setTimeStamp(time);
```

Comment: time.put("time",ServerValue.TIMESTAMP); -> This line gives a compilation error. (Required 'java.lang.String', found 'java.Util.Map'

Comment: Which type is the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: Map<String, String>

Comment: Sorry,I just test in my code .And it did not solved.@AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the `timestamp` in your Firebase database, your setting it as a `Map` and when you are retrieving, you are retrieving it as a `Long`. So, you can nest the property in a more generic `HashMap<String, Object>` that it can get into your database as either a single long value ("date", "longValue") or as the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` as you did, which is a HashMap that looks like this: ("date", {".sv", "servertime"}).

To get the time and date i recomand you using the following method:

```
String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return "date";
    }
}
```

To get only the date i recomand you using the following method:

```
String getDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return "date";
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I cannot set it as a HashMap.(When retrieving to the pojo again, it says what I said in the question.) 2. I cannot set it as a long. (Cannot set a Map(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP) to a long when uploading.

Comment: You can only set it as a `Map`, this what am i saying and retrieving as a Long. When uploading only as a Map.

Comment: Maybe I cannot make you understand, but I cannot manually only upload an object. The code is `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("id11").setValue(pojo)`. I cannot manually upload a part of the object.

Comment: I think that i did not completely understood you. What does it mean you "cannot manually upload a part of the object"?